# Square root of floating point numbers

Tags: roots

How can i calculate squareroot of 0.0004. How i deal with .000 section. can anyone explain? I know how to find the square root of normal numbers but the 0.000 section is hard to find.

Comment: 0.0004= 4 x 10^{-4} so sqrt(0.0004)= 2 x 10^{-2}= 0.02.

Comment: $\sqrt{0.0004} = \sqrt{4 \cdot 10^{-4}} = \sqrt{4} \cdot \sqrt{10^{-4}} = \cdots$

Answer (score 1):

$\sqrt{a \cdot 10^{-2b}}
=\sqrt{a}\cdot 10^{-b}$
and
$\sqrt{a \cdot 10^{-(2b+1)}}
=\sqrt{10a}\cdot 10^{-(b+1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{\sqrt{10000 x}}{100} = \sqrt x  $$
here $x$ is 0.0004, what is $10000x \; \; ? \;$